# UMAP UnsupportedParforsError while trying to reduce dimensions of dataframe features

Tags: python, numpy, machine-learning

```
UnsupportedParforsError: Failed in nopython mode pipeline (step: native lowering)
The 'parallel' target is not currently supported on 32 bit hardware.
During: lowering "id=1[LoopNest(index_variable = parfor_index.51, range = (0, 
$38binary_subscr.17, 1))]{46: <ir.Block at 
c:\users\tima\appdata\local\programs\python\python38-32\lib\site-packages\umap\utils.py 
(32)>}Var(parfor_index.51, utils.py:32)" at c:\users\tima\appdata\local\programs\python\python38-32\lib\site-packages\umap\utils.py(32)
```

This error occurs when I'm trying to reduce the four-dimension data frame to two dimensions by using the UMAP library. I'm using 64-bit OS Windows but unfortunately, it still throws this error. I've tried to reinstall umap-learn from pip but it didn't help.

```
data = df[features].to_numpy()
X = data
reducer = umap.UMAP(n_neighbors=400, min_dist=0.4, random_state=322)
reducer.fit(data)
```

Is there any way to deal with it in python?

Comment: Did you install a 32-bit Python?  Make sure you install an amd64 Python on your 64-bit Windows system.